# Volumes and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a docker-compose.yml file that contains a `--volumes-from` instruction. Does anyone know the syntax?

I have been looking online for some time now, and it appears that the `--volumes-from` command is only available as a docker command. I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aug. 2022:

[brandt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687896/brandt) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701130/volumes-and-docker-compose/35701933?noredirect=1#comment129461901_35701933) to the updated [docker-compose documentation](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/compose/compose-file/index.md).

---

Note August 2017: with [docker-compose version 3, regarding volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes):

> The top-level **[volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference)** key defines a named volume and references it from each service’s volumes list.
> This replaces `volumes_from` in earlier versions of the Compose file format.  See [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) and [Volume Plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/) for general information on volumes.

Example:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock:/var/run/postgres/postgres.sock"
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

volumes:
  mydata:
  dbdata:
```

> This example shows a named volume (`mydata`) being used by the `web` service, and a bind mount defined for a single service (first path under `db` service volumes).
>
> The `db` service also uses a named volume called `dbdata` (second path under `db` service volumes), but defines it using the old string format for mounting a named volume.
>
> Named volumes must be listed under the top-level volumes key, as shown.

---

February 2016:

The [`docs/compose-file.md`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/compose-file.md#volumes_from) mentions:

> Mount all of the volumes from another service or container, optionally specifying read-only access(ro) or read-write(rw).

(If no access level is specified, then read-write will be used.)

```
volumes_from:
 - service_name
 - service_name:ro
 - container:container_name
 - container:container_name:rw
```

For instance ([from this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2990) or [this one](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2988))

```
version: "2"

services:
...
  db:
    image: mongo:3.0.8
    volumes_from:
      - dbdata
    networks:
      - back
    links:
      - dbdata

 dbdata:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - /data/db
```

---

Comment: @pie ok, I will amend the answer for version 3

Comment: @Pietro Amended.

Comment: The docker-compose reference doesn't elaborate on the syntax of the top-level volume key. How do I configure the source, options, etc. for a named volume under the top-level key?

Comment: @Ungeheuer 5 years later, I am not sure.

Comment: haha didn't notice the date on that Von! Sorry :)

Comment: @Ungeheuer No problem: do edit this answer if you find more details about those options.

Comment: August 2022: compose-file docs: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/tree/master/compose/compose-file