# Docker volume adding a file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can we add a file to docker volume in docker-compose.

Later i will bind the docker volume in continer.

My question is how to add a file into docker volume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Volumes and docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701130/volumes-and-docker-compose)

Comment: hi sorry nope. I wish to know after docker volume created how i can move config file in host to the volume. Using container i can bind mount but i need move to volume

Answer (score 0):

The docker volume is mapped to a physical host machine folder.

So, you have to add the file(s) you want by a script, after a call to **docker-compose**.

Comment: how can we find physical location? can it be done in docker compsoe itself?

Comment: Sure, at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes you can learn the right syntax.

Comment: i saw it but it didn't say how transfer files via docker compose. we can use inspect to see location